# Page curl left and right for uiwebview with html contents

Tags: webview, swipe

I am working on a epub book reader application and displaying the contents of
book in web view and i want to give a horizontal page curl effect for that just a turning the page of a real book. I couldnt find any tutorials for that . Help is appreciated

Comment: I also need same help... Life Hacker did you get any content related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? https://github.com/zeroCoder1/Epub-Reader/blob/master/testPubb%2FtestPubb%2FViewController.m#L41

// Aw, stackoverflow need me to enter at least 30 characters, so here's it another wasted characters they need. ;p